# Automatically set full size for all my images in all my post and page?

Tags: images

I have near 800 post/page in my site and 3800 images.
I actually set Large Size to 600px width but in my new theme i want my image width be 880px.

So i would like to switch all my image to Full-Size and don't do that one by one. :D

Have you any idea to do that ?

I try to delete Large, etc, but always have 404 with :

```
   www.truc.fr/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/survival-600x351.jpg
```

in my post instead of

```
   www.truc.fr/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/survival.jpg
```

Thank you for the delete and sorry for the bad English i'm french.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `the_content` filter to filter all post content and replace img sources.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'show_full_sized_images' );
/**
 * Replaces all -600x999 images with full image url
 * @param string $content
 * @return string
 */
function show_full_sized_images( $content ) {

    $pattern = '~(http[^\'"]*)(-600x[0-9]{2,4})(\.jpe?g|png|gif)~i';

    $m = preg_match_all( $pattern, $content, $matches );

    echo '<pre>' . esc_html( print_r( $matches, 1 ) ) . '</pre>';

    return preg_replace( $pattern, '$1$3', $content );
}
```

You'll also need to add following css because width may be limited by `width` attribute in `img` tag:

```
img {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it make me 2 errors :


`Warning: preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 52 in /home/nopanicv4/wp-content/themes/NoPanic/functions.php on line 55


Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 52 in /home/nopanicv4/wp-content/themes/NoPanic/functions.php on line 59`

Comment: And it's not really my question, i would like to switch all Large image by Full Size image in the Wysiwyg of all my post/page.

Comment: @Fluti Compilation error fixed.